# Angular JSON using $scope data as key value

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I have the following function which creates a new JSON object using data submitted through a form.

```
$scope.createEvent = function() {
  var cal = new CAL.API();
  cal.year = {August: [{day:$scope.calDay, title: $scope.calTitle, summary: $scope.calSummary, description: $scope.calDescrip}]};
  cal.$save(function(result){
    $scope.calendar.push(result);
  });
}
```

I'd like to make the key, in this case the month August to be dynamic and pick up a $scope.calMonth field from the form. For some reason replacing the month with a dynamic $scope field doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to make this key value dynamic?

For reference here is my schema

```
year: { 
August: [
  {
    day: String,
    title: String,
    summary: String,
    description: String
  }
      ],
September: [
  {
    day: String,
    title: String,
    summary: String,
    description: String
  }
      ]
}
});
```

Here is my form:

```
<form name="calForm" ng-submit="createEvent()">
  <select ng-model="calMonth" required>
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Day" ng-model="calDay" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="calTitle" required>
  <textarea type="text" placeholder="Summary" ng-model="calSummary" required></textarea>
  <br>
  <button class="addAdmin" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var month = [{day:$scope.calDay, title: $scope.calTitle, summary: $scope.calSummary, description: $scope.calDescrip}];
cal.year = {};
cal.year[$scope.calMonth] = month;
```

Essentially you need to use the square bracket notation with dynamic key values. Also note setting the `year` to a blank object first, so that the dynamic month can be set.